# Screenshot comes out black on Wayland

Tags: c++, wayland

I found this [code](http://ted.mielczarek.org/code/screenshot/) to take a screenshot on Ted Mielczarek's website.

```
/*
 * gdk-screenshot.cpp: Save a screenshot of the root window in .png format.
 *  If a filename is specified as the first argument on the commandline,
 *  then the image will be saved to that filename. Otherwise, the image will
 *  be saved as "screenshot.png" in the current working directory.
 *
 * Compile with:
 * g++ -o gdk-screenshot gdk-screenshot.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs gdk-x11-2.0`
 */

#include <gdk/gdk.h>
#include <gdk/gdkx.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  gdk_init(&argc, &argv);
  GdkWindow* window = window = gdk_get_default_root_window ();
  GdkPixbuf* screenshot = gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable (NULL, window, NULL,
                            0, 0, 0, 0,
                            gdk_screen_width(),
                            gdk_screen_height());
  GError* error = NULL;
  const char* filename = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "screenshot.png";
  return TRUE == gdk_pixbuf_save (screenshot, filename, "png",
                  &error, NULL);
}
```

I compiled it as described and it appears to work, in that it produces an image with the correct dimensions, but the screenshot is entirely black.
 [image: black screenshot]

This appears to be a [common](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1398556) [issue](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=98672) on systems running Wayland (I'm running Archlinux with Wayland), so my question is:

What modifications need to be made to this code to get it to produce a proper screenshot on Wayland (and X)?

Comment: The reply to the second bug you link states that it can't be done: "By design, Wayland is a lot more secure than X11 and does not allow one application to capture the content of other applications' windows"

Comment: `gnome-screenshot` and gimp are both able to produce a screenshot of another program under Wayland, and Super+s is supposed to be set up for screenshots under Weston (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/taking_a_screenshot#Weston) which I assume could be triggered by any program. I wish that person had included some explanation of why they feel this is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

I use Xlib to take screenshots, but this method can't work on Wayland. Every time I run to xgetimage, I report an error. After looking up the data, I find Wayland doesn't allow such screenshots. However, in this way, I can still get the correct screen size.

Now I use DBUS to call the session bus of the system to take a screenshot, which I learned from reading the source code of Gnome screenshot.

This is a simple summary code:

```
    method_name = "Screenshot";
    method_params = g_variant_new ("(bbs)",
                                     TRUE,
                                     FALSE, /* flash */
                                     filename);

    connection = g_application_get_dbus_connection (g_application_get_default ());
    g_dbus_connection_call_sync (connection,
                               "org.gnome.Shell.Screenshot",
                               "/org/gnome/Shell/Screenshot",
                               "org.gnome.Shell.Screenshot",
                               method_name,
                               method_params,
                               NULL,
                               G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE,
                               -1,
                               NULL,
                               &error);
```

The document link is here:
https://developer.gnome.org/references

The GitHub of Gnome screenshot is here:
https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-screenshot

Comment: This code does not work anymore.